# Is $g f_n$ convergentin measure if $f_n$ is convergent in measure to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let a seguence $f_n$ of real valued measurable functions on a space $X$ with a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ be convergent in measure to $0$.
Let a function $g$ be measurable.
Is then  $gf_n$ convergent to $0$ with respect to measure $\mu$ ?

Comment: $|f_ng|>\epsilon$ implies $|f_n|>\epsilon / M$ or $|g|>M$.

Comment: If $M:=sup }g(x)|>0$, then $gf_n$ tends to zero with respect to $\mu$. But I don't know whether this additional assumption is needed or not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True for finite measures but false with just $\sigma-$ finiteness. [For finite measures use my comment above].

On the real line with Lebesgue measure let $f_n(x)=\frac  1n $ for $n <x<n+1 $ and $0$ elsewhere. Let $g(x)=x$ for all $x$. Then $f_n \to 0$ in measure but $f_ng>1$ on $(n,n+1)$.